# AngularJs + Bootstrap: dropdown missing gap between each others

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a weird issue with the UI when trying to use angularjs to render some bootstrap dropdown: the gap between each dropdown is gone, like this pic (see the 2 first dropdowns)

[image: Missing gap between 2 first dropdowns]

This is my code:

```
var lcApp = angular.module('lcApp', [], function () {});

lcApp.factory('historyService', function() {
    return {        
        filters: [
            { name: 'year', label: 'Năm', type: 'dropdown', value: '', options: [{ label: '2014', value: '2014' }, { label: '2013', value: '2013' }, { label: '2012', value: '2012' }] },
            { name: 'month', label: 'Tháng', type: 'dropdown', value: '', options: [{ label: '2014', value: '2014' }, { label: '2013', value: '2013' }, { label: '2012', value: '2012' }] }
        ]
    };
});

lcApp.controller('historyController',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $log, $window, historyService) {

        // get filter data
        $scope.filterData = historyService.filters;
        $log.info('Load filters success');

        // filter click
        $scope.filterClick = function(filter, option) {
            filter.value = option.value;
        };

    });
```

The UI:

```
<div class="btn-group" ng-repeat="flt in filterData">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Tháng</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Ngày</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="portlet-input input-inline input-medium">
    <div class="input-icon right">
        <i class="icon-magnifier"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="tên hoặc email" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

Nothing special, just a ngRepeat directive to render my filter as dropdown.

Comment: Do the buttons have a `margin: 0` attached to them?

Comment: Hi, using firebug to identify the HTML, nothing special was added to the DOM element, they're all the same, I don't really know why, tested on both Chrome and Firefox :(

Comment: My guess is that they're `inline-block` elements with either some margin set to them, or the browser's default margin not set to 0.

Comment: No margin was used to make the gap between them, I still dont know why there's gap over there

Comment: There's not a need for a margin to be there. If you don't set it at 0, the browsers will sometimes implement margins of their own. That's why we use CSS resets and normalizers.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `btn-group` wrappers, they make buttons stack together.